# pull out column 2,3 of a 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

hi all i have a 2d array and i want to create a new 2d array with only the column 2,3

here is my code

```
#!/user
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import urllib2
import numpy as np


url = 'https://api.bmreports.com/BMRS/FUELINST/v1?APIKey=66ky5jo5p5w0vbd&ServiceType=CSV'
url2 = 'https://api.bmreports.com/BMRS/FUELINSTHHCUR/v1?APIKey=66ky5jo5p5w0vbd&ServiceType=CSV'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
cr = csv.reader(response)


arr = np.genfromtxt(response,delimiter=",", skip_header=1, skip_footer=2,dtype=None)

data = arr[:, [1:2]]


print data
```

so the data comes back like this

```
[('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'CCGT', 10430, 35.8, 10282, 35.2, 205996, 32. )
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OCGT',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,     17,  0. )
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OIL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. )
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'COAL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. )
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'NUCLEAR',  6963, 23.9,  6970, 23.9, 167591, 26. )
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'WIND',  6986, 24. ,  7061, 24.2, 160036, 24.9)
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'PS',   297,  1. ,   412,  1.4,   8136,  1.3)
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'NPSHYD',   322,  1.1,   319,  1.1,   8015,  1.2)
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OTHER',   129,  0.4,   128,  0.4,   3093,  0.5)
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTFR',  1494,  5.1,  1494,  5.1,  31731,  4.9)
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTIRL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,   2650,  0.4)
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTNED',   882,  3. ,   880,  3. ,  18991,  2.9)
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTEW',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. )
 ('FUELINSTHHCUR', 'BIOMASS',  1608,  5.5,  1630,  5.6,  37688,  5.9)]
```

i'm trying to create a new 2d array that only brings back columns back so it looks like this

```
[('CCGT', 10430)
 ('OCGT',     0)
 ('OIL',     0)
 ('COAL',     0)
 ('NUCLEAR',  6963)
 ('WIND',  6986)
 ('PS',   297)
 ('NPSHYD',   322)
 ('OTHER',   129)
 ('INTFR',  1494)
 ('INTIRL',     0)
 ('INTNED',   882)
 ('INTEW',     0)
 ('BIOMASS',  1608)]
```

Comment: You should change `[2:3]` to [2, 3].

Comment: @kasramvd i'm still getting this error File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/LiveGrid/LiveGrid.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = arr[:, 2, 4]
IndexError: too many indices for array

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to use a Numpy array for preserving your items not a list, then you can pass the column indices in a list to the second axis to get the desire results:

```
data = arr[:, [2, 3]]
```

Or slice like following:

```
data = arr[:, 2:4]
```

Also if the string you're reading is correctly formatted instead of using `csv`
you can use [`fromstring()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)
function to load your data.

Comment: if i do 'data = arr[:, [2, 3]]' i get list indices must be integers, not tuple. If i remove the comma 'data = arr[: [2, 3]]' i get  slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method. If i do the data = arr[: 2:4 i get the full row back and only for the first row

Comment: That's because `arr` is not a numpy array it's a list. You should either use a numpy array or as I said load the text with `np.fromstring`.

Comment: ah ok i will give the numpy way ago

Comment: i'm updated my question with my new code to use numpy and getfromtxt however i'm now with your example getting the error too many indices for array. this is for both examples you gave

Answer (score 0):

If you review this code sample it may help you.

It assumes that the first values you have collected turn out to be individual strings in a numpy array....so each line contains commas, and quoted elements but they are all embedded in a single element.

The var 'lst' is a list used to step through all the array elements and create multidimensional list of lists containing the comma separated elements as individual strings.

The var 'tmp' is a numpy array constructed of the newly parsed 'lst'.

The var 'data' is the sliced numpy array from 'tmp' with just the columns you were looking for.

Hope that helps...

```
    import numpy as np

    def ElementSplit(x) : return x.split(",")
    ElementSplit = np.vectorize(ElementSplit)

    arr = np.array([["'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'CCGT', 10430, 35.8, 10282, 35.2, 205996, 32. "],
     ["'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OCGT',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,     17,  0. "],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OIL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. "],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'COAL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. "],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'NUCLEAR',  6963, 23.9,  6970, 23.9, 167591, 26. "],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'WIND',  6986, 24. ,  7061, 24.2, 160036, 24.9"],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'PS',   297,  1. ,   412,  1.4,   8136,  1.3"],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'NPSHYD',   322,  1.1,   319,  1.1,   8015,  1.2"],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OTHER',   129,  0.4,   128,  0.4,   3093,  0.5"],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTFR',  1494,  5.1,  1494,  5.1,  31731,  4.9"],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTIRL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,   2650,  0.4"],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTNED',   882,  3. ,   880,  3. ,  18991,  2.9"],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTEW',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. "],
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'BIOMASS',  1608,  5.5,  1630,  5.6,  37688,  5.9"]])

    print " --arr--"
    print arr

    lst = []
    for items in arr:
        lst.append(items[0].split(", "))

    print " --lst--"
    print lst

    exit

    #data = arr[:]
    tmp = np.array(lst)

    print " --tmp--"
    print tmp

    data = tmp[:,[1,2]]

    print " --data--"
    print data
```

and the output looks like this....

```
    $python main.py
     --arr--
    [["'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'CCGT', 10430, 35.8, 10282, 35.2, 205996, 32. "]
     ["'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OCGT',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,     17,  0. "]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OIL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. "]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'COAL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. "]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'NUCLEAR',  6963, 23.9,  6970, 23.9, 167591, 26. "]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'WIND',  6986, 24. ,  7061, 24.2, 160036, 24.9"]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'PS',   297,  1. ,   412,  1.4,   8136,  1.3"]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'NPSHYD',   322,  1.1,   319,  1.1,   8015,  1.2"]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'OTHER',   129,  0.4,   128,  0.4,   3093,  0.5"]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTFR',  1494,  5.1,  1494,  5.1,  31731,  4.9"]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTIRL',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,   2650,  0.4"]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTNED',   882,  3. ,   880,  3. ,  18991,  2.9"]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'INTEW',     0,  0. ,     0,  0. ,      0,  0. "]
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR', 'BIOMASS',  1608,  5.5,  1630,  5.6,  37688,  5.9"]]
     --lst--
    [["'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'CCGT'", '10430', '35.8', '10282', '35.2', '205996', '32. '], ["'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'OCGT'", '    0', ' 0. ', '    0', ' 0. ', '    17', ' 0. '], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'OIL'", '    0', ' 0. ', '    0', ' 0. ', '     0', ' 0. '], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'COAL'", '    0', ' 0. ', '    0', ' 0. ', '     0', ' 0. '], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'NUCLEAR'", ' 6963', '23.9', ' 6970', '23.9', '167591', '26. '], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'WIND'", ' 6986', '24. ', ' 7061', '24.2', '160036', '24.9'], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'PS'", '  297', ' 1. ', '  412', ' 1.4', '  8136', ' 1.3'], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'NPSHYD'", '  322', ' 1.1', '  319', ' 1.1', '  8015', ' 1.2'], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'OTHER'", '  129', ' 0.4', '  128', ' 0.4', '  3093', ' 0.5'], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'INTFR'", ' 1494', ' 5.1', ' 1494', ' 5.1', ' 31731', ' 4.9'], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'INTIRL'", '    0', ' 0. ', '    0', ' 0. ', '  2650', ' 0.4'], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'INTNED'", '  882', ' 3. ', '  880', ' 3. ', ' 18991', ' 2.9'], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'INTEW'", '    0', ' 0. ', '    0', ' 0. ', '     0', ' 0. '], [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'", "'BIOMASS'", ' 1608', ' 5.5', ' 1630', ' 5.6', ' 37688', ' 5.9']]
     --tmp--
    [["'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'CCGT'" '10430' '35.8' '10282' '35.2' '205996' '32. ']
     ["'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'OCGT'" '    0' ' 0. ' '    0' ' 0. ' '    17' ' 0. ']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'OIL'" '    0' ' 0. ' '    0' ' 0. ' '     0' ' 0. ']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'COAL'" '    0' ' 0. ' '    0' ' 0. ' '     0' ' 0. ']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'NUCLEAR'" ' 6963' '23.9' ' 6970' '23.9' '167591'
      '26. ']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'WIND'" ' 6986' '24. ' ' 7061' '24.2' '160036' '24.9']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'PS'" '  297' ' 1. ' '  412' ' 1.4' '  8136' ' 1.3']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'NPSHYD'" '  322' ' 1.1' '  319' ' 1.1' '  8015'
      ' 1.2']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'OTHER'" '  129' ' 0.4' '  128' ' 0.4' '  3093'
      ' 0.5']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'INTFR'" ' 1494' ' 5.1' ' 1494' ' 5.1' ' 31731'
      ' 4.9']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'INTIRL'" '    0' ' 0. ' '    0' ' 0. ' '  2650'
      ' 0.4']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'INTNED'" '  882' ' 3. ' '  880' ' 3. ' ' 18991'
      ' 2.9']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'INTEW'" '    0' ' 0. ' '    0' ' 0. ' '     0'
      ' 0. ']
     [" 'FUELINSTHHCUR'" "'BIOMASS'" ' 1608' ' 5.5' ' 1630' ' 5.6' ' 37688'
      ' 5.9']]
     --data--
    [["'CCGT'" '10430']
     ["'OCGT'" '    0']
     ["'OIL'" '    0']
     ["'COAL'" '    0']
     ["'NUCLEAR'" ' 6963']
     ["'WIND'" ' 6986']
     ["'PS'" '  297']
     ["'NPSHYD'" '  322']
     ["'OTHER'" '  129']
     ["'INTFR'" ' 1494']
     ["'INTIRL'" '    0']
     ["'INTNED'" '  882']
     ["'INTEW'" '    0']
     ["'BIOMASS'" ' 1608']]
```